# convert float to string without altering the float

Tags: go

I am converting a float to a string like this in Golang

```
a := strconv.FormatFloat(-3.6739403974420544e-15, 'f', -1, 64)
```

It's giving me this as output

```
-0.0000000000000036739403974420544
```

However, I would rather have this as output

```
   "-3.673940397442059e-15"
```

In the title to this question, I said "without altering" the float.  By "altering" I am referring to the addition of the 0s in place of the e-15. is there a way to do it?

Comment: All type conversions in Go don't alter the original.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are just using the wrong format specifier:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(strconv.FormatFloat(-3.6739403974420544e-15, 'e', -1, 64))
}
```

Output:

```
-3.6739403974420544e-15
```

The [docs](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#FormatFloat) show the other formats as well.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it

```
f := -3.6739403974420544e-15
fmt.Println(fmt.Sprint(f))
```